# How to add an EventHandler for Child MenuItems click event to the following Dynamic Menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The below Dynamic menu shows data from database but I want to create an event handler for the child menu items created for handling the click event raised. Also please help me with the event handler code to track down which child menu is click (for example, based on the value of the child menu item).

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
    string connect = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con1;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        con1 = new SqlConnection(connect);
        con1.Open();
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            PopulateMenuItems();
        } else {
            Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["str"].ToString();
        }
    }

    private void PopulateMenuItems() {
        DataTable dt_GetParentData = GetMenuData_Parent();
        AddTopMenuItems(dt_GetParentData);
    }

    private DataTable GetMenuData_Child() {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  Department, FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Name FROM Employees", con1)) {
            SqlDataAdapter da_menuchild = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt_menuchild = new DataTable();
            da_menuchild.Fill(dt_menuchild);
            return dt_menuchild;
        }

    }

    private DataTable GetMenuData_Parent() { 
        using(SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Department FROM Employees", con1)) {
            SqlDataAdapter da_menuparent = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataTable dt_menuparent = new DataTable();
            da_menuparent.Fill(dt_menuparent);
            return dt_menuparent;
        }
    }

    private void AddTopMenuItems(DataTable dt_Parent) {
        DataTable dtchild = GetMenuData_Child();
        DataView parent_view = new DataView(dt_Parent);

        foreach (DataRowView row in parent_view) {
            MenuItem newParentItem = new MenuItem(row["Department"].ToString());
            Menu2.Items.Add(newParentItem);
            AddChildMenuItems(dtchild,newParentItem);
        }
    }

    private void AddChildMenuItems(DataTable dtchild, MenuItem parentitem) {
        string parent = parentitem.Value.ToString();
        DataView childview = new DataView(dtchild);
        childview.RowFilter = String.Format("Department='{0}'", parent);

        foreach(DataRowView row1 in childview) {
            MenuItem newChildItem = new MenuItem(row1["Name"].ToString());
            parentitem.ChildItems.Add(newChildItem);
            newChildItem.NavigateUrl = "Default2.aspx?str=" + newChildItem.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just handle Menu2.MenuItemClick event?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menuitemclick.aspx

In the event args, you'd have access to the Item clicked so you could determine which one the user clicked and react accordingly.